# Help me please, how to draw this picture in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How to draw two arrows near the ring?

How to draw here:
[image]
Minimum working example:

```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\newcommand{\arcarrow}[3]{%
    % inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle,
    % end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{2.9}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{3.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{5}
    \draw[very thick] (\astart+\atip:\rin)
    arc (\astart+\atip:\aend:\rin)
    -- (\aend-\atip:\rmid)
    -- (\aend:\rout)   arc (\aend:\astart+\atip:\rout)
    -- (\astart:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[
    decoration = {
        text along path,
        text = {#3},
        text align = {align = center},
        raise = -0.5ex
    },
    decorate
    ](\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [] {Version 1\ldots n};
   \arcarrow{ 85}{  3}{ PLAN  }
   \arcarrow{270}{357}{ DO    }
   \arcarrow{182}{269}{ CHECK }
   \arcarrow{176}{ 96}{ ACT   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to move the arrows, consider this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\newcommand{\arcarrow}[4][draw,very thick]{%
    % inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle,
    % end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{2.9}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{3.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{5}
    \path[#1] (\astart+\atip:\rin)
    arc (\astart+\atip:\aend:\rin)
    -- (\aend-\atip:\rmid)
    -- (\aend:\rout)   arc (\aend:\astart+\atip:\rout)
    -- (\astart:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[
    decoration = {
        text along path,
        text = {#4},
        text align = {align = center},
        raise = -0.5ex
    },
    decorate
    ](\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}




\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [] {Version 1\ldots n};
   \arcarrow{ 85}{  3}{ PLAN  }
   \arcarrow{270}{357}{ DO    }
   \arcarrow{182}{269}{ CHECK }
   \arcarrow{176}{ 96}{ ACT   }
   \begin{scope}[xshift=6.84cm,yshift=-2mm,xscale=-1]
   \arcarrow{357}{270}{ EAT   }
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm,yshift=3cm,xscale=-1]
   \arcarrow{357}{270}{ SLEEP }
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want something closer to your screen shot, consider

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\newcommand{\arcarrow}[4][draw,very thick]{%
    % inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle,
    % end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{2.9}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{3.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{5}
    \path[#1] (\astart+\atip:\rin)
    arc (\astart+\atip:\aend:\rin)
    -- (\aend-\atip:\rmid)
    -- (\aend:\rout)   arc (\aend:\astart+\atip:\rout)
    -- (\astart:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[
    decoration = {text color=white,
        text along path,
        text = {#4},
        text align = {align = center},
        raise = -0.5ex
    },
    decorate
    ](\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}




\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [] {Version 1\ldots n};
   \arcarrow[fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.3]{ 85}{  3}{ PLAN  }
   \arcarrow[fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.3]{270}{357}{ DO    }
   \arcarrow[fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.3]{182}{269}{ CHECK }
   \arcarrow[fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.3]{176}{ 96}{ ACT   }
   \begin{scope}[xshift=6.84cm,yshift=-5mm,xscale=-1,rotate=3]
   \arcarrow[fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.3]{357}{270}{ EAT   }
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm,yshift=3cm,xscale=-1]
   \arcarrow[fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.3]{357}{270}{ SLEEP }
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]